# помогите правильно составить условия для ботов в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Задача следующая, сайт написан на ангулар, нужно чтобы **все боты** отправлялись на отрендеренную страницу, кроме одного, а именно YandexMetrika (2.0/3.0), вот мой пример htaccess, который отправляет всех ботов:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested pattern is file and file doesn't exist, send 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# Prerender.io stuff
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|Yandex|MailRuConnect|OdklBot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|Yahoo|Bingbot|vkShare|Feedfetcher-Google|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=

    # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

**нужно условие которое запретит боту** YandexMetrika (2.0/3.0) на http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 (отрендеренную версию страницы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуру, подскажите, правильное ли я нашел решение?

```
# Prerender.io stuff
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|MailRuConnect|OdklBot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|Yahoo|Bingbot|vkShare|Feedfetcher-Google|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandex(Bot|Favicons|Webmaster|Pagechecker|Antivirus|Images|Video|Media) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=

    # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```